# How to have absolutely no bounce when colliding two objects?

Tags: collision, godot, gdscript

I have a node called "SlidingBlock" which is a **RigidBody2D**, its mode is **Character** so I can move it with the physics engine but not rotate it. It also has a **CollisionShape2D**.

I've programmed a kicking action on which I set a value for its linear velocity, like this:

`block_touched.linear_velocity.x = BLOCK_SPEED`

The block moves until it collides with another **RigidBody2D** which is in mode **Static** and, when it collides, it goes one pixel forward and then back. It looks weird in my game which is a somewhat low resolution pixel art game.

I tried creating a **Physics Material** with **Bounce** set to 0 with no success. How can I achieve a collision with absolutely no bounce effect?

Comment: This is a known bug, see https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/16505.

Comment: @Calinou Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Godot still lets you pick between Godot's Physics and Bullet Physics, maybe try switching and see what happens? There's a good chance it still won't work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Googling it now it seems the Bullet physics backend is only available for 3D, which won't help me here. ️

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've been doing all my work in 3D recently, so i'm thinking in 3D. Do you have contact monitoring turned on for the rigidbody?

Comment: Yes, Contact Monitor is set to "On" and Contacts Reported set to "1", though I don't quite get how these work yet. I'll give a more thorough look into the docs.

Comment: Yeah, that might be something to look at. Only other thing I can think is to put all the movement logic in `_physics_process()` instead of  `_process()`.

Comment: Sorry, also try enabling continuous detection (CD) on the RigidBody, and set it to "cast shape".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213340/discussion-between-telmo-trooper-and-christopher-bennett).

Comment: "cast shape" has never really worked to remove the bounce for me. I have had better luck turning up ProjectSettings > General > Physics > Common > Physics Fps.  I have mine set to 120. I keep an inverse constant of that value around so I can multiply it against my forces to keep them around the same strength. You will still get bounce, but it seems dampened. Hope they fix it soon...